# Pycharm and Dash Apps

Tags: python, pycharm

Ok, here's the situation: I am trying to use Dash in Pycharm. Pycharm does not allow pip install but does allow you to click install if you have a line such as
: import dash.

In older versions of Dash, you would have to import dash_core_components as dcc, but in the newest version of Dash you can use the line
: from dash import dcc, html

I am now trying to install dash_bootstrap_components. Using the line from dash import dbc does not work.

In Jupyter the line import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc works but that line does not work in Pycharm and Pycharm does not allow me to install dash_bootstrap_components.

I also tried to pip install dash-bootstrap-components at the command line, which works, but pycharm still does not recognize the app.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're facing a common issue with IDEs and Python environments. PyCharm, like many other IDEs, can manage multiple Python environments, and it's possible that the environment you're using in PyCharm is different from the one you're using in Jupyter or at the command line. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you resolve the issue:

1. **Check the Python Interpreter in PyCharm**:

   - Open your project in PyCharm.
   - Go to `File` > `Settings` (or `PyCharm` > `Preferences` on macOS).
   - Under the `Project` section, click on `Python Interpreter`.
   - Note the path of the interpreter that's currently selected. This is the Python environment that PyCharm is using for your project.
2. **Install `dash-bootstrap-components` in PyCharm's Python Environment**:

   - In the `Python Interpreter` settings (from step 1), you'll see a list of installed packages.
   - Click on the `+` button at the bottom to add a new package.
   - Search for `dash-bootstrap-components` and install it.
3. **Alternatively, Use the Same Environment as Jupyter**:

   - If you want to use the same environment in PyCharm as you do in Jupyter:

     - First, find out the path to Jupyter's Python interpreter by running this in a Jupyter cell:

       ```py
       import sys
       print(sys.executable)
       ```
     - Copy the path.
     - Go back to PyCharm's `Python Interpreter` settings.
     - Click on the gear icon ⚙️ > `Add`.
     - Choose `Existing environment` and paste the path you copied into the `Interpreter` field.
     - Click `OK` to use this environment for your PyCharm project.
4. **Check Your Code**:

   - After ensuring that `dash-bootstrap-components` is installed in the correct environment, try importing it in your PyCharm code:

     ```py
     import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
     ```
5. **Ensure Consistency**:

   - If you often switch between Jupyter and PyCharm, consider using virtual environments (`venv` or `conda`) to ensure consistency in package versions and dependencies across different projects and platforms.
6. **Last Resort - Manual Installation**:

   - If all else fails, you can manually download the `dash-bootstrap-components` package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) and install it using `pip` pointing to PyCharm's interpreter:

     ```bash
     path_to_pycharm_interpreter -m pip install path_to_downloaded_package
     ```

     Replace `path_to_pycharm_interpreter` with the path you noted in step 1 and `path_to_downloaded_package` with the path to the downloaded `dash-bootstrap-components` package.

By following these steps, you should be able to successfully use `dash-bootstrap-components` in PyCharm. If you continue to face issues, please let me know, and I'll be happy to assist further.